# scope function does not work in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to call a function defined in the controller, but due to some silly mistake it does not call, here is my code. It should alert 1 defined in the `getCustomerID` function. The scope variables are set properly like `this.title`

HTML

```
 <ons-template id="home.html">
      <ons-page ng-controller="Home as page">
        <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="left">
            <ons-toolbar-button onclick="fn.open()">
              <ons-icon icon="md-menu"></ons-icon>
            </ons-toolbar-button>
          </div>
          <div class="center">
            {{page.title}}
          </div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <p style="text-align: center;  padding-top: 20px;">
        Choose Client : 
        <select ng-model="filterCondition.operator" ng-change="getCustomerID()">
            <option  ng-repeat="x in customers" value="{{x.id}}">{{x.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <ons-button ng-click="page.getCustomerID()">Call</ons-button>
        </p>            

        <div id="map"></div>

        <br/>
        <ons-button modifier="large" onclick="mylocation()">My Location</ons-button>
      </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
```

JS

```
    app.controller('Home', function($scope){
    $scope.page = {
        title : "CRGroup",
        name : localStorage.getItem("name"),
        email : localStorage.getItem("email"),
        profilepic : localStorage.getItem("profilepic"),
    }  

    $scope.filterCondition={
        operator: '1'
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://XXXXX.php',        
        async: false,
        data: {},
        success: function (response) {                      
            $scope.customers = response;            
        },
        error: function (response) {
            $scope.error = true;
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });

    $scope.page.getCustomerID = function() {
        alert(1);
    }   
});
```

Comment: You've mixed `controller as` and `$scope` syntax. You need to choose one or the other.

Comment: @Lex +1 Also try to avoid using  $.ajax. Use $http instead. If you need configuration for $http use .config phase

Comment: @Vitalii Good point. Also, if the OP sticks with `controller as` syntax a local variable for `this` will need to be created because `this.` inside the promise resolution will not refer to the controller.

Comment: using `async:false` it's a bad practice.

Comment: @Lex Please check the updated code, the `getCustomerID` function still does not call :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still mixing `controller as` and `$scope`. If you are going to use `controller as` I would recommend removing all the `$scope` stuff from your controller. Here is how you might restructure your stuff to use `controller as` syntax. *I don't know where your `onclick` functions are nor why you are using `onclick` instead of `ng-click` so I left those as is.*

HTML

```
<ons-template id="home.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="Home as page">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button onclick="fn.open()">
                    <ons-icon icon="md-menu"></ons-icon>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center">
                {{page.title}}
            </div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <p style="text-align: center;  padding-top: 20px;">
            Choose Client : 
            <select ng-model="page.filterCondition.operator" ng-change="page.getCustomerID()">
                <option ng-repeat="x in page.customers" value="{{x.id}}">{{x.name}}</option>
            </select>
            <ons-button ng-click="page.getCustomerID()">Call</ons-button>
        </p>            
        <div id="map"></div>
        <br/>
        <ons-button modifier="large" onclick="mylocation()">My Location</ons-button>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('Home', function($http) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.title = "xxxx";
    _this.name = localStorage.getItem("name");
    _this.email = localStorage.getItem("email");
    _this.profilepic = localStorage.getItem("profilepic"); 
    _this.filterCondition = {
        operator: '1'
    };
    $http.get('http://xxxx.php')
        .then(function(response) {
            _this.customers = response.Data; 
           // I use Typescript and put my web service calls in a service 
           // so I can never remember if you need to use response.Data here,
           // but I think you do
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            _this.error = true;
        });
    _this.getCustomerID = function() {
        alert(1);
    }   
});
```

Comment: I literally copied your code and changed the URL, the `_this.title = "xxxx";' works, but `_this.customers = response.Data; ` and `_this.getCustomerID` does not work, this is really strange

Comment: Try adding `_this.customers = []` somewhere under `var _this = this;`, but before the `$http.get` call. It may be that not having that initialized is keeping the view from detecting an update. As for why the call to `page.getCustomerID()` is not working I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't be. Double check that you have spelled them the same in the controller and markup.

Comment: Well, i initialized the customers array as well as double checked the spelling of the getCustomerID function, really strange! does angular js version matters?

Comment: Controller as was added in version 1.1.5 I believe so I would be surprised if it were a version issue. Perhaps update your question with the exact code you are using now and we can spot some subtle issue? Or create a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue.

Comment: thanks for the help, the issue is fixed, the problem was the sequence of the js files declaration.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the controller syntax `as` you must define your functions with `this` not with `$scope`

If you change the `$scope.getCustomerID = function...` to read `this.getCustomerID = function...`

same will go for your other functions.

Also note that you are going to have issues with the `x in customers` part as well as you need to do `x in page.customers` and in your controller you will need to do `this.customers` But if you define it in a sub function it also won't work unless you ensure that you hoist the context.

Comment: Simply changing all `$scope.` to `this.` will cause unexpected behavior in the return from the promise.

Comment: @Lex, yes I edited the answer to mention hoisting the context as well. Personally I don't like the as syntax much. But it is the recommended way.

Comment: If you use Typescript it saves you from quite a bit of this pain since the transpilation to js already creates a local variable for `this`. If you're doing any Angular dev I strongly recommend using Typescript.

Comment: @TyroneWilson i did change everything in JS from `$scope` to `this` as i understand your point that  I am mixing it, and I also changed `x in customers` to `x in page.customers`, now even customer list stopped loading in the `select`, should i post the updated code?

Comment: Don't shoot me please but I use CoffeeScript :P

Comment: @RajeshVishnani, perhaps it would be easier to just use the `$scope`. So change `Home as page` to be just `Home`. leave your controller as is and then change where you have page.getCustomerID to just getCustomerID and it should work.

Comment: @TyroneWilson Initially i had done the same but I got `$scope` is not defined, i almost checked everything, but could not found the problem, does changing the sequence of declaring scripts affect?

Comment: @TyroneWilson Please check the updated code, the function still does not call :(

Comment: @RajeshVishnani, I will be back online in about 30 min. you can give me a shout on 'tyrone-wilson' on skype and I will help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143897/discussion-between-tyrone-wilson-and-rajesh-vishnani).

Answer (score 0):

Check the changes:

```
app.controller('Home', function($scope){
$scope.page = {
  title : "xxxx",
  name : localStorage.getItem("name");
  email : localStorage.getItem("email");
  profilepic : localStorage.getItem("profilepic"); 

  }  

$scope.filterCondition={
    operator: '1'
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://xxxx.php',     
    async: false,
    data: {},
    success: function (response) {                      
        $scope.customers = response;            
    },
    error: function (response) {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
});

$scope.page.getCustomerID = function() {
    alert(1);
}   
});
```

And Try using $http service provided by angular instead of using ajax calls. That way, I think you can also eliminate the $scope.$apply(). FYI, using $scope.$apply is not a good practice. And try to stay in angular rather than using jquery or vanilla js methods.

Comment: can you please post HTML change as well, because I have changed your JS accordingly, but `getCustomerID` still does not work.

Comment: please check the updated code, the `getCustomerID` function still does not call :(